# Better / Faster Result with smaller batch Size linear classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, batchsize

I'm currently training multiple linear classifier with tensorflow and I found something which is strange.

If the batch_size is small, my results are better ( the model learn faster)
I'm working on FashionMNIST

```
epochs = 300
batch_size = 5000

# Create and fit model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear", input_dim=28*28))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax", input_dim=1))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=[categorical_crossentropy], metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
model.fit(x_train, y_one_hot_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_one_hot_val), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

**Results**

Batch-size : 20000 and 200 epochs

```
loss: 2.7494 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2201 - val_loss: 2.8695 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2281
```

Batch-size : 10000 and 200 epochs

```
loss: 1.7487 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3336 - val_loss: 1.8268 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3331
```

Batch-size : 2000 and 200 epochs

```
loss: 1.2906 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5123 - val_loss: 1.3247 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5113
```

Batch-size : 1000 and 200 epochs

```
loss: 1.1080 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5246 - val_loss: 1.1261 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5273
```

Do you know why I got these kind of results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch size impacts learning significantly. What happens when you put a batch through your network is that you average the gradients. The concept is that if your batch size is big enough, this will provide a stable enough estimate of what the gradient of the full dataset would be. By taking samples from your dataset, you estimate the gradient while reducing computational cost significantly. The lower you go, the less accurate your esttimate will be, however in some cases these noisy gradients can actually help escape local minima. When it is too low, your network weights can just jump around if your data is noisy and it might be unable to learn or it converges very slowly, thus negatively impacting total computation time.

Comment: @arunjose-intel, how would you choose batch size when you train your model?

Comment: @Sherzod various features like hardware(cpu/gpu cores), dataset ,loss function etc are to be considered choosing batch size.  There is no one size that fits all it is best to experiment with different batch sizes and choose the one that suits your purpose best. Ie some may have purpose to reduce computation cost whilst accuracy might be more important for others.         Normally I try out powers of 2. (I start with 32 and go up or down) on intution gained from similar data and loss functions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, it should be noted that increasing the batch size while keeping the number of epochs the same will result in fewer training steps overall. This is because one epoch is the number of steps it takes to iterate over the data once, which is smaller if the batches are bigger.
E.g., increasing batch size by 10 will reduce the number of training steps by 10. So it's not really a fair comparison. Your model with batch size 20000 only gets 600 training steps (3 steps per epoch) whereas the model with batch size 1000 gets 12000 (60 steps per epoch).

Comment: But what is the impact of a step , because 1 epoch is only using each image once right? It will iterate a différent number of step but the total of images used for one epoch will be the same